# Automatic update of a cell based on the value of a cell in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically update the content of a cell based on the value of a cell in another sheet ?

That original cell's value is based on a drop down menu.

Could someone exlpain to me how to make it work ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

In a spreadsheet software, cells are identified by their column as a letter and their line as a number.
For example first top left cell is A1.
So if in a cell, lets say D5, you want the same content as E8. You put `=E8` in cell D5.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell whose value you want in a cell on another sheet you have to add the name of sheet containing the value to the reference. So instead of, for example, =E5 you'd enter something like =othersheet.E5 if the name of the source sheet is, in fact "othersheet". By far the easiest way to do this is simple to type an equal sign in the cell you want to have the value copied into and without typing anything else, navigate to the other sheet and click in the cell whose value you want.